# Blank PNG file after conversion with GhostScript.NET

Tags: c#, pdf, png, ghostscript

In my software I make 2 PDF files from 1 input file using iTextSharp. I'd like to convert these files into 2 different PNG images using GS, but something strange happens. I use this code for the conversion:

```
GhostscriptRasterizer rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer();

rasterizer.Open(newFilePath1, gsInfo, false);
Image image = rasterizer.GetPage(300, 300, 1);
image.Save(subDirPath + serCod + "_S1.png");
rasterizer.Close();

rasterizer.Open(newFilePath2, gsInfo, false);
image = rasterizer.GetPage(300, 300, 1);
image.Save(subDirPath + serCod + "_S2.png");
rasterizer.Close();
```

When I save the first image it shows like a blank page and the file name is the same of newFilePath1 without .pdf but with .png.

When I look at the second image with the same file name as newFilePath2 with .png instead of .pdf, it has the image of the newFilePath1 pdf file.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you try the same operation using Ghostscript from the command line (instead of through Ghostscript.NET). If you get the same result then you can open a bug report at **[bugs.ghostscript.com](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/)** and someone can look at it (remember to include the PDF file(s) and command lines).

Otherwise you'll have to contact jhabjan (the author of Ghostscript.NET) and have him investigate it.

Comment: Could you tell me what the conversion command line is? Thank you

Comment: Well no, I have no idea what Ghostscript.NET uses for a command line, sorry.

Comment: Hi @mac_ref, can you attach pdf's you are testing somewhere so I can see what's going on?

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/00000000010001319377s1
If I use Ghostscript I can see the file correctly. If I use ImageMagick with Magick.NET I can see it too and I can convert it to PNG, but when I try to use Ghostscript.NET, a blank page comes out.

Comment: I'd like to add that the pdf file is made with iTextSharp